# How to add custom namespace to HTML element in JSF?

Tags: java, facebook, jsf

I'm trying to add my custom namespace to `<html>` element in JSF `.xhtml` file (actually, this namespace is not mine, it's Facebook's):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
    xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

JSF/Mojarra gives me a warning:

```
Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml 
declared with prefix fb but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.
```

I can understand what it means, but how to solve the problem?

Comment: How exactly is a warning a problem? Isn't your sole question how to suppress/hide this warning?

Comment: Well, the warning tells me about an incorrect behavior of the software. JSF is trying to load `taglibrary`, which is not what I want it to do..

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Certain browsers, like Safari, will display a big red error box if you use the fb:login-button (or similar) tag, without exporting xmlns:fb in the xhtml, but JSF doesn't export namespaces to the html element.

Comment: If you still need to know that, I had the same problem and answered my own question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162017/facebook-social-plugins-and-jsf/. Cheers, Andreas

Comment: Facebook has deprecated FBML...[link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/)

Answer (score 1):

You can **suppress the warning** by adding the following lines in the **web.xml** file of your application:

```
..
      <!-- Debug Output for Development -->
      <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
      </context-param>
...
```

Comment: Well, the point is not to suppress the warning, but to instruct JSF not to treat my namespace as a `taglibrary`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go with this.

1. delete the namespace if you aren't using it
2. let JSF know about the namespace

To let JSF you either need the appropriate library on your classpath that is defining the taglibrary (maybe you are using a facebook.jar or something?). You will need to include this library in your .war file.

Or, if it is your own namespace, create a [taglibrary file](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-facelets/#N10298) and make sure it is loaded in the web.xml, so that Facelets (I hope you are using Facelets with JSF, or JSF 2) will load the taglibrary and know the namespace.